# main.py on Pico W behaves differently in Thonny than running standalone

Tags: pi-pico-w

I have a Pico W that is serving a webpage that displays output from a plant monitor. It updates every couple of seconds with temp, moisture etc. The program is saved as main.py and runs fine in Thonny, with the pico connected via USB to the laptop like normal. BUT - when I stop the program, close Thonny, unplug the device and plug it straight back in again without starting Thonny, I would expect main.py to run exactly as before. And it almost does, except that the webpage returns 500 internal server error. If I mash refresh in frustration it sometimes flickers up the correct plant monitor page for a second, but with zero values for temp. So something is breaking with the connection or readings from the plant monitor

But how can running main.py as a standalone board be different from running it in Thonny? In my limited understanding they should behave the same way.

In Thonny I have connected the Pico W as Micropython (Raspberry Pi Pico) from the menu in the very bottom right. 
The plant monitor is this one: https://monkmakes.com/downloads/instructions_pmon_pico.pdf 
It uses Microdot web server. 
If I comment out the plant monitoring bit then the web server seems to run OK - but why is it different from running it through Thonny? Is the Pico running out of memory or something if it's not connected to the laptop?

I've tried and replicated this with two different Picos and two different plant monitors, also tried many different cables and power sources. Any help gratefully received!

**UPDATE**
Thanks for suggestions so far.
I set up logs for the webserver and saw

```
ValueError: invalid syntax for integer with base 10
GET / 500
```

Then I found a patch for the code provided by the plant monitor that fixed this - there was an int that should have been a float. But I still don't understand why it was  only a problem when running the board by itself, not through Thonny

And it's still behaving differently. The monitor reports three values, wetness, temp, humidity. These work fine in Thonny but are transposed when running from the board - wetness shows the value for humidity, temp shows the value for wetness and humidity shows temp.

Here's my **main.py**

```
from microdot import Microdot
import mm_wlan
from pmon import PlantMonitor
from machine import Pin, Timer

ssid = 'my_ssid'
password = 'my_password'
pm = PlantMonitor()
app = Microdot()
led = Pin('LED', Pin.OUT)
timer = Timer()

# # define the web page
html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<html>
    <head> <title>My Plant</title> </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pico W Plant Monitor</h1>
        <h2>Water: {water}</h2>
        <h2>Temp (C): {temp}</h2>
        <h2>Humidity: {humidity}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
"""

# # define the web app
@app.route('/')
def index(request):
    w = pm.get_wetness()
    t = pm.get_temp()
    h = pm.get_humidity()
    response = html.format(water=w, temp=t, humidity=h)
    return response, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}

# #  actual code
mm_wlan.connect_to_network(ssid, password)
app.run(port=1980, debug=True)
```

**microdot** is the [Microdot web server](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microdot/tree/main). 
**pmon** is provided by [plant monitor](https://github.com/monkmakes/pmon/tree/main)

I guess really my main question is: *Is it normal to have variations when running on the board through Thonny versus on the board by itself?*

I'm careful to select Micropython (Raspberry Pi Pico) in thonny. I get that different versions of Python will have different results but I thought Thonny here was running micropython directly on the board?

Comment: Too many things could be different.  Python loads modules from files based on things in its environment.  Try running a main.py that gives you version and filepath of all the stuff you import, and the python version itself.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. I thought the version of micropython running in Thonny would be the same as the version running on the board. Is that not correct? I can view the version of micropython running in Thonny but I don't know how to see the version running on the board. All the imports refer to other .py files saved on the board, apart from **machine** and **time**

Comment: Post your actual code. Are you logging errors to a file?

Comment: 500 usually mean that the script generating the web page crashed. The usual way to find out why is to either log what happens to a file or the web server log, or to attach a debugger.

Comment: Log w,t,h to a file as soon as read, I wonder it the plant monitor is getting the wrong values for some reason.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP hasn't followed up to the requests for clarification, and the question is not answerable without it.